# Pandas dataframe: convert dataframe numeric value to 2 to the power of this numeric value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numeric, calc

[image]

How do I get the value of 2^(column of pandas dataframe) in another col of a dataframe.

For example:

| Value | 2^Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

Comment: I see you're shifting the accepted answer, you can only choose **one** ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.power`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.power.html) :

```
import numpy as np

df["2^Value"] = np.power(2, df["Value"])
```

Or simply, `2 ** df["Value"]` as suggested by @*B Remmelzwaal*.

Output :

```
print(df)

   Value  2^Value
0      0        1
1      1        2
2      3        8
3      4       16
```

*Here is some stats/timing :*

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't use `2 ** df["Value"]`?

Comment: I added your suggestion to the answer ;) and it seems to be a little bit faster than `np.power`.

Comment: Or [`rpow`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rpow.html) ;)

Comment: Love the stats.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`rpow`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rpow.html):

```
df['2^Value'] = df['Value'].rpow(2)
```

Output:

```
   Value  2^Value
0      0        1
1      1        2
2      2        4
3      3        8
4      4       16
```

Comment: A built-in of course. I added  a perfplot btw ;)

Comment: @Timeless I saw that, now you're addicted ;)

Comment: Still low key but I'm trying to step up ;)

Comment: @Timeless how's your nice GitHub project going? Last I checked the links were 404

Comment: This week I got busy IRL and here in SO but I plan to get back on it next week. I'll keep you posted ;)

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to seeing it (no pressure) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.apply` with a lambda function

```
df["new_column"] = df["Value"].apply(lambda x: x**2)
```

In python the power operator is `**`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function to each row in a dataframe by using the df.apply method. See [this documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to learn how the method is used. Here is some untested code to get you started.

```
# a simple function that takes a number and returns
# 2^n of that number
def calculate_2_n(n):
    return 2**n

# use the df.apply method to apply that function to each of the 
# cells in the 'Value' column of the DataFrame
df['2_n_value'] = df.apply(lambda row : calculate_2_n(row['Value']), axis = 1)
```

This code is a modified version of the code from [this G4G example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/apply-function-to-every-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe/)